# Object count is off by a factor of 2

Tags: windbg, dotmemory

I have a dotMemory profiling session and I was unable to find the memory leak, so I did the following:

1. Start dotMemory session
2. Attach WinDbg and break into the process
3. Take a snapshot in dotMemory
4. Let the process continue (`g`) so that dotMemory can take the snapshop
5. After the snapshot was taken, break into the process again

Like that I should get identical results, if the application is in an idle state, i.e. does nothing (well, it runs the message pump).

Looking at the objects in that snapshot of dotMemory, I can see 88000 objects of type JProperty:

[image: dotMemory Screenshot]

In WinDbg however, I see the double amount of objects:

```
0:021> !dumpheap -stat -type JProperty
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007fe7d3a3c28    83930      3357200 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JPropertyKeyedCollection
000007fe7d3a4ef0   177104      4250496 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty+JPropertyList
000007fe7d3a4b80   177104     18418816 Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty
Total 438138 objects
```

Who's wrong - or is it a known issue to use the debugger along with dotMemory?

I'm using dotMemory 2018.1.4 and WinDbg 10.0.15063 on Windows 7, debugging a x64 program, if any of that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug in dotMemory 2018.1.4. For some reasons I did not get updates automatically. I have now updated to version 2018.2.1 and the object count is identical.

I tried to find an issue in [their bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DMRY?q=%23major%20fixed%20in:%202018.2), but I didn't find one.

Comment: I know another reason which could explain it, dotMemory doesn't show objects reported by Profiling API but not reachable from any roots (yes, sometimes GC leaves some objects not reachable from roots in memory and MS Profiling API reports them). Can you see in WinDbg number of objects reachable from roots?